# The input is entering 2 if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input - 12:00:00AM
Issue - entering both the if statements 1st and 3rd only want it to enter 1st

```
OriginalTime = input()
if "1" in OriginalTime[0] and "2" in OriginalTime[1] and "AM" in OriginalTime:
    excepxtion(OriginalTime)
if "1" in OriginalTime[0] and "2" in OriginalTime[1] and "PM" in OriginalTime:
    AMconversion(OriginalTime)
if "AM" in OriginalTime:
    AMconversion(OriginalTime)
if "PM" in OriginalTime:
    PMconversion(OriginalTime)
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when there is neither `"AM"` nor `"PM"` in the input?

Comment: As an exercise this might be ok, but for 'real' use you should look at the `datetime` module

Comment: move th 3rd if as elif below the first if

Comment: @quamrana did not think of that new to programming it is a problem on hackerrank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote four independent `if`s; if the input contains all four strings (`1`, `2`, `AM`, `PM`), your code will enter all four `if` clauses.  Instead, your logic appears to be choosing a conversion: check for `12` in the input, then `AM` or `PM`.

Most of all, I expect that you can do this most easily by doing your time conversion through the `datetime` package (i.e. browser search for the many examples).  For your code in particular:

```
OriginalTime = input()

if OriginalTime.startswith("12") and "AM" in OriginalTime:
    excepxtion(OriginalTime)
elif OriginalTime.startswith("12") and "PM" in OriginalTime:
    AMconversion(OriginalTime)
elif "AM" in OriginalTime:
    AMconversion(OriginalTime)
elif "PM" in OriginalTime:
    PMconversion(OriginalTime)
else:
    excepxtion(OriginalTime)
```

I added the last clause to catch any cases that aren't what your `if` statements expected.  This is generally good programming practice.  For instance, if your user enters a "time" of `Half past dinner`, you now have a code block to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Use elif instead of if statements if you only want one to be entered max

Answer (score 0):

If you write multiple `if` statements, all will be executed. However, if you go for `elif` statements, they will be executed only if the above `if` statements do not get executed.

```
OriginalTime = input()
if "1" in OriginalTime[0] and "2" in OriginalTime[1] and "AM" in OriginalTime:
    excepxtion(OriginalTime)
elif "1" in OriginalTime[0] and "2" in OriginalTime[1] and "PM" in OriginalTime:
    AMconversion(OriginalTime)
elif "AM" in OriginalTime:
    AMconversion(OriginalTime)
elif "PM" in OriginalTime:
    PMconversion(OriginalTime)
```

Try the above code which uses `elif`. This simply means, `else-if`. So, if one `if` statement is not executed it will execute the `elif` statements. Once any of the (`if` or `elif`) condition is true and it is executed, your program will not look for other `elif` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `elif` or `else if` instead of `if` in your later statements if you want them to be all in the same block